# ionic build on iOS error with OneSignal and pod install

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor, onesignal

I have an app with OneSignal Notifications.
I'm using @capacitor/cli@3.3.1. If I enable use_frameworks!  and use_modular_headers!
in Podfile, then pod install shows the error:

`!] The 'Pods-App' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (/Users/.../Pods/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework/OneSignal.framework)`

Removing use_frameworks! , the error I get is:

`` [!] Using Swift static libraries with custom module maps is currently not supported. Please build `Capacitor` as a framework or remove the custom module map. ``

Answer (score 0):

Add the OneSignal plugin name to the `staticPlugins` array in `capacitor.config.json`:

```json
{
    "appId": "com.example.myapp",
    "appName": "MyApp",
    "cordova": {
        "staticPlugins": [
            "onesignal-cordova-plugin"
        ]
    }
}
```

See https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config:

```
/**
 * List of Cordova plugins that need to be static but are not
 * already in the static plugin list.
 *
 * @since 3.3.0
 */
 staticPlugins?: string[];
```